# Using $this when not in object context error after upgrading

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, upgrade

I updated my app from cakephp 1.3 to 2.4 but I have a lot of errors and I don't know how to solve them... This error appeared after I made the database connection and correcting other errors. This is the screenshot that shows the errors: [image: error after update]
This is the index.ctp part that it's causing error:

```
<?php 
    if($app_galleries)
    {
        $nr_gl = 0;
        foreach($app_galleries as $app_gallery)
        {
            $poza = AppController::getPrimaryPicture($app_gallery,'PictureToGallery','Gallery','picture_to_gallery_id','galleries');
            if($nr_gl%3==0)
            {
                echo '<div class="box_galleries">';
            }
?>
     <div class="box_gallery <?php echo ($nr_gl%3==2) ? 'noMarginRight' : '';?>">
```

I replaced `$this->request->webroot` with `$this->webroot` but still doesn't work...any ideas why? This is the view.php line 473 error:

```
if ($view !== false && $viewFileName = $this->_getViewFileName($view)) {
        $this->_currentType = self::TYPE_VIEW;
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('View.beforeRender', $this, array($viewFileName)));
        $this->Blocks->set('content', $this->_render($viewFileName));
        $this->getEventManager()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('View.afterRender', $this, array($viewFileName)));
    }
```

This is the getPrimaryPicture function:

```
function getPrimaryPicture($var,$toImage,$image,$field,$path)
    {
        unset($poza);
        if(empty($var[$toImage]))
        {
            $poza = $this->webroot.'css/front/default_image.png';
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($var[$toImage] as $img)
            {
                if(isset($var[$image])){
                    if($var[$image][$field]==$img['id'])
                    {
                        $poza = $this->webroot.'uploaded/'.$path.'/thumb_'.$img['name'];
                    }
                }else{
                    if($var[$field]==$img['id'])
                    {
                        $poza = $this->webroot.'uploaded/'.$path.'/thumb_'.$img['name'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!isset($poza))
            {
                 $poza = $this->webroot.'uploaded/'.$path.'/thumb_'.$var[$toImage][0]['name'];
            }
        }
        return $poza;
    }
```

Comment: you're missing the closing brackets for `if` and `foreach`

Comment: @Cemal I'm closing it at the end of the file, if I would post all the code this will be a very big post and we don't want this

Comment: how do you implement `AppController` class? or at least what is the definition of this method `getPrimaryPicture` ?

Comment: @hassan I posted it in another comment